# Avverbio per esprimere il fatto che si parla facendo molto rumore

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

Quale avverbio devo usare per esprimere che si parla ad alta voce facendo molto rumore? Per esempio, quale avverbio posso usare per completare la frase seguente?

> Scusa, non ti sento bene perché gli altri parlano molto __________.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alcune possibilità:

> **parlano (molto|troppo) forte**  (la forma di gran lunga più comune)
>
> **parlano a voce (molto|troppo) alta**
>
> **fanno rumore**
>
> **fanno (troppo|un gran) chiasso|baccano**
>
> **fanno (troppo|un gran) casino** (molto colloquiale, spec. usato nel nord)

Teoricamente anche

> **parlano (molto|troppo) rumorosamente**

ma non lo direbbe nessuno.

Comment: **Strepito** e' un altro sostantivo che si può usare : Rumore forte e indistinto; fracasso, fragore: lo strepito delle voci, dei tuoni,  delle macchine.

Comment: Giusto, c'è anche il verbo "strepitare".

Comment: @Josh61: E la frase sarebbe "... gli altri fanno (un gran) strepito"?

Comment: Anche *parlano troppo forte*, sottintendendo *perché possa sentirti*.

Comment: @egreg grazie, l'ho aggiunto.

Comment: @Charo - yes correct!!